# HP Proliant 360 G4 hangs on Ethernet Boot Agent

Tags: hp

My server hangs on Ethernet Boot Agent. I can't access the BIOS.

It used to work fine. I can access the RAID controller, but it stops booting and fails to respond on key inputs once it gets to the Ethernet Boot Agent stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried resetting the BIOS? You may need to pull the CMOS battery if you can't get into the BIOS at all.

Answer (score 1):

Get the last firmware CD from HP and make certain to upgrade everything if you have not already. This server was retired in March of 2006 so using the latest and greatest Smart Start/Firmware downloads from HP may not work for you.

This is the 8.60 firmware link: http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=0&prodSeriesId=397638&swItem=MTX-124beffbed3842cea0b9b3f962&prodNameId=3288140&swEnvOID=2026&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=4&idx=1

you are not stating which O/S or 32/64 bit so make certain you get the smart start that pertains to your needs. They can be found under the Drivers and software link on the left on this page.

Also, your raid controller may have failed. There are 5 or so different RAID controllers for that machine. The 6i being the base card. If you run the firmware CD/DVD it will honk if it does not see the RAID controller.

Hope this helps

Comment: It would be impossible to do that, you need to get into the BIOS before you can upgrade the firmware. My OS is not really relevant since the problem is in POST.